# Handling select event from Google Charts in Angular 6 (without wrapper such as ng2-google-charts!)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-visualization, event-listener

I'm using Google Charts with Angular 6 without a wrapper such as ng2-google-charts. I've implemented it succesfully based on this tutorial: http://anthonygiretti.com/2017/10/12/using-google-charts-in-angular-4-project-part-2/

However, now I want to add an event listener for click events inside the chart. For example when you click on a bar, it needs to run some function.

So, according to the Google Chart docs I need to add a listener like so:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);
```

So I added:

`google.visualization.events.addListener(chartFunc(), 'select', this.mySelectHandler);`

However, mySelectHandler doesn't run when I click on for example a bar in the chart.

I've looked at [this very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35080471/handling-select-event-from-google-charts-in-angular-v2). But the answer didn't work for me.

These are the services that build the chart:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { GoogleChartsBaseService } from './google-charts-base.service';
import { ChartConfigModel } from '../../models/chart-config.model';

declare var google: any;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ChartService extends GoogleChartsBaseService {

  constructor() { super(); }

  public buildChart(elementId: string, data: any[], config: ChartConfigModel): void {
    const chartFunc = () =>  new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById(elementId));

    this.buildGoogleChart(data, chartFunc, config);
  }
}
```

```js
declare const google: any;

export class GoogleChartsBaseService {

  constructor() {
    google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
  }

  public mySelectHandler() {
    console.log('hi');
  }

  protected buildGoogleChart(data: any[], chartFunc: any, options: any): void {
    const func = (chartFunc, options) => {
      const datatable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);
      const formatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({ pattern: 'MMM d, yyyy | H:mm' });
      google.visualization.events.addListener(chartFunc(), 'select', this.mySelectHandler);
      formatter.format(datatable, 0);
      chartFunc().draw(datatable, options);
    };
    const callback = () => func(chartFunc, options);
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(callback);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you did most of it right. It's just that your `chartFunc` always returns a `new` instance of the `google.visualization.ComboChart`. So basically you're attaching the event listener to one chart and clicking on another.

Try to store the chart you get from `chartFunc` in a variable and use that to attach the event listener and also draw the data.

Try something like this:

```
declare const google: any;

export class GoogleChartsBaseService {

  constructor() {
    google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
  }

  public mySelectHandler() {
    console.log('hi');
  }

  protected buildGoogleChart(data: any[], chartFunc: any, options: any): void {
    const func = (chartFunc, options) => {
      const datatable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);
      const formatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({ pattern: 'MMM d, yyyy | H:mm' });
      const myChart = chartFunc();
      google.visualization.events.addListener(myChart, 'select', this.mySelectHandler);
      formatter.format(datatable, 0);
      myChart.draw(datatable, options);
    };
    const callback = () => func(chartFunc, options);
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(callback);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes! This actually worked! My mySelectHandler is firing now. Thanks!!